# How to display hidden div when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am needing the hidden divs to be displayed ONLY when the pertaining  link is clicked. I have been on a couple forums looking for an answer, but have yet asked the question myself. I am using Foundation Grid System and have very little knowledge of javascript/jquery.  Thanks in advance for help that is given.

To view the markup..please follow the link: http://simplicitdesignanddevelopment.com/TENANT%20REP%20ZURB/tenant_reputations_home.html

Comment: I JUST UPDATED THE QUESTION.  I BELIEVE MY PREVIOS QUESTION WASN"T ASKED LIKE IT SHOULD OF BEEN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your code, this jQuery function will work.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/ffW5y/)

```
var links = $('.links a');
links.on('click',function(){
    var n = links.index(this);
    $('.row > div:not(.links)').eq(n).toggle();
});​
```

The second click on the same link will hide the paragraph. If it's not what you want, replace `toggle()` with `show()`, or `fadeIn()`, or `slideDown()`...

You need to [include jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) at first, right? ;-)

---

If you're having trouble implementing the function above in your real layout, please replace this part of your code:

```
<div class="row">
<div>Content to be shown when the first link is clicked</div>
/* ...etc... */
```

with this one:

```
<div class="row" id="rowTarget">
<div>Content to be shown when the first link is clicked</div>
/* ...etc... */
```

and my function with this:

```
var links = $('.links a');
links.on('click',function(){
    var n = links.index(this);
    $('#rowTarget > div').eq(n).toggle();
});​
```

**[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/TszPL/)**

Comment: That is exactly the thing I am going for.  Only my list of links are horizontal, and the divs need to be shown right under the horizontal list of link.  The divs will be taking up 100% width of screen.  Also, only one div should be displayed at a time.  I hope I am not a pain in the arse!!  I am taking js classes next semester tho, so one day i will be a pro!

Comment: @JeremyFlaugher for the "one at the time" request, replace `.eq(n).toggle();` with `.hide().eq(n).show();` . For the layout part, maybe you should open another question ;)

Comment: Once I tried putting this in my layout it isn't working..I put the page on my server..could you take a look at the code and give me advice.  I am wanting pretty much what you have given me, but I cant get it to work in my current layout. I want the divs to be hidden until one of the links are clicked.I would like only one hidden dive to be displayed at a time, and will disappear if i click the same link twice.  http://simplicitdesignanddevelopment.com/TENANT%20REP%20ZURB/tenant_reputations_home.html

Comment: Well @JeremyFlaugher , your markup there is completely different! Check this fiddle, and please follow the commented istructions: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/hrEDG/

Comment: Thank you GIONAF very much with your help.  Your example and time have gotten me through this problem.  Sorry about the differences in markup, I wasn't really wanting to put the real source code out there as the project is yet to be finished.  Thank you for taking the time to make the very understandable fiddle, and getting me through this problem!!  I will pass it forward!!

Comment: You're welcome @JeremyFlaugher :) good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can easily make links show/hide divs

```
$(function(){
   $('a#resources').click(function(){
       $('div#row div').eq(8).show();
   });

});
```

or by using toggle you can show/hide it:

```
 $(function(){
   $('a#resources').click(function(){
       $('div#row div').eq(8).toggle();
   });

});
```

(at least now I counted it to be the eight `'div#row div'` ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search-tenant").click(function(e){
   $("#row div").eq(1).show();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

And similarly for the other links. Just replace the `#search-tenant` with the `id` of the link, and the `.eq(1)` with the position of the hidden element inside the `<div id="row">`.

However, I advice you to use another type of element for this, other than a link. If you are going to have a link that isn't serving the purpose of a link...then why use it?

Comment: I do it that way because I want to include the image inside the link, making the image itself clickable along with the text.  If done this way, when a user puts in /resources, the hidden div connected with the link is shown.

Comment: That makes sense. You could then add an alternative link to the elements that could be used when JavaScript is turned off.

Comment: I haven't worked with Foundation...but I guess you could add an id to the `<div>` that has the hidden info. `<div id="row" class="row">` or such.